# Graph Theory Inductive proof

Tags: graph-theory, induction

This is just a simple Proof by induction that I hoped one of you could check.

**Definition** A graph is called a *tree* if it is a connected graph which contains no cycles.

**Theorem** Let G be a tree. Then

$$|V(G)| = |E(G)| + 1.$$

*Proof* Consider the 'base case' where $|V(G)| = 2$. Then clearly $|E(G)| = 1$. We make the assumption that if $|V(G)| = n - 1$ then $|E(G)| = n - 2$ and proceed to add a vertex to the graph. If the tree structure is to be preserved then only one edge can join this vertex to the graph. Hence, $|V(G)| = n$ implies that $|E(G)| = n-1$. More concisely,

$$|V(G)| = |E(G)| + 1$$

as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You probably need to include your formal definition of Tree, otherwise the induction step isn't guaranteed (what I call Tree you may call Lattice...)

Comment: I've included a definition of tree in the edit, thanks.

Comment: "If the tree structure is to be preserved then only one edge can join this vertex to the graph." why? I think you need to show this formally.

Comment: Would it be enough to say that any pair of vertices in a tree is joined by a unique path in the graph?

Comment: You can put any precondition you want (note that the one you just given is more stringent than "connected without cycle", as it states uniqueness of the path), but you will still need to show how from your conditions you can derive "If the tree structure is to be preserved then only one edge can join this vertex to the graph"

Comment: Do you think it would help if I gave a proof of the uniqueness of this path? I'm almost certain it follows directly from the definition of tree that I gave and that the statement that the structure is preserved if you add one vertex is made more formal by the proof of the uniqueness statement. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the graph is bidirectional (otherwise a tree in the common sense is not connected if hierarchical)

When you say there is a unique path and the graph is connected and acyclic, you are basically saying [1]:

```
\foreach(v1, v2) | v1 != v2 -> \exists ! p | v1->p->v2
```

Let's call our new node x . It must be connected to the rest of the graph, so it needs to be connected to at least one vertex. Let's say it's directly connected to v2:

```
v2 -> x && x -> v2
```

then we get, by lemma 1

```
\exists ! p1 | v1 -> p1 -> v2 -> x
```

If x was directly connected to any other vertex v3, then you would have:

```
(\exists ! p2 | v1 -> p2 -> v3 -> x && p2 != p1) =>  p1->v2 != p2->v3
```

which leads to a contradiction because now we have two different paths from v1 to x, respectively p1->v2 and p2->v3 .

Therefore x must be connected by at least 1 edge (per connected definition) and at most 1 edge (otherwise contradiction). Therefore exactly one edge.

Comment: I can't format (noob here), can someone pretty print it?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a separate proof that asserts the same thing.

Comment: @Ed_4434 if you feel this is the correct answer, please mark it as so. You can always untick it later if someone spots a mistake.

Comment: Let G be a tree and let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be distinct paths joining vertices $v, w \in V(G)$. Then from$P_1$ and $P_2$ we can construct a cycle, contradicting the fact that G is a tree. Hence distinct vertices must be joined via a unique path.